# Why does event delegation ES6 listener track input clicks as button clicks?

Tags: javascript, events, ecmascript-6, event-handling

I am not sure why when I want to listen for input clicks separate from button clicks it does not discriminate? I put the listener on the UL for this as the LIs are dynamically added (event delegation). When you click on a checkbox it is recognized as a button.

```
function toggleDone(e) {
    if (!e.target.matches('button'))
    { return; }
```

Here is the js/html

```
 <li>
   <input type="checkbox" data-index="${i}" id="item${i}" 
${item.chosen ? 'checked' : ''} /> 
   <label for="item${i}">${item.text} </label>
   <button title="delete" id="del${i}">X</button>
 </li>
```

I hope this isn't too much of a newbie question, but I'd like to understand if I'm doing something wrong, or if it might be an actual bug.

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue in a fiddle? Or a stacksnippet

Comment: Can you create a [mcve]? Currently this isn't complete enough to reproduce the described behavior, and having code that matches the description allows us to help you more easily.

Comment: That isn't html, it's an html template.... and not a flavor I recognize. So it doesn't really help us help you... Also what does this have to do with ES6?

Comment: @JaredSmith the template looks like an ES6 template literal, and possibly they might think that [`.matches()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches) is part of ES6, even though that is part of the W3C Web APIs and not of ECMAScript.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts all reasonable guesses given the ambiguities like the double quotes. I guess we will have to see if the OP checks back in, but it's been ~15 minutes and I'm voting to close this for lacking MCVE.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am using `e.target.localName` instead of `e.target` and `match` instead of `matches`

```js
let lis = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("li"));


lis.map((li) =>{
  li.addEventListener("click", toggleDone )
})



function toggleDone(e) {
  //console.dir(e.target.localName)
  let str = e.target.localName;
  console.clear();
 if (!str.match('button'))
    { console.log("KK") }else{console.log("OK")}
}
```

```html
<ul> 
<li>
   <input type="checkbox" data-index="1" id="item1"  checked /> 
   <label for="item1">item 1 text</label>
   <button title="delete" id="del1">X</button>
 </li>
 <li>
   <input type="checkbox" data-index="2" id="item2" /> 
   <label for="item2">item 2 text</label>
   <button title="delete" id="del2">X</button>
 </li>
 <li>
   <input type="checkbox" data-index="3" id="item3" /> 
   <label for="item3">item 1 text</label>
   <button title="delete" id="del3">X</button>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: OP meant [`matches`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches), not [`name.match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

Comment: @Bergi Thank you for your comment. I thought the OP wanted an working example. He is not mentioning in his question that he whant `matches`

Comment: He did mention event delegation though, which is traditionally done with CSS selectors. There's no reason this part of the code wouldn't work. (In fact, as the comments show, his code would be expected to work, nobody can reproduce the problem - the question should be closed not answered)